# Visual C#: Add ribbon button to start tab? (Outlook add in)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I´m using the ribbon designer in visual studio 2012 for a outlook add-in.

I need to add several ribbon buttons to different existing tabs in the Outlook ribbon.

Right know my button shows up in the "Add in´s" tab, so how do I set it to built in tab?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add it as a tab under the tabs element, like in the XML below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
   <ribbon>
      <tabs>
         <tab id="MyNewTab" label="My Tab" visible="true">
           <group id="TabGroup" label="My Group" visible="true">
               <button id="TestButton" onAction="TestButton_Click" label="Test Button" size="large" />
           </group>
        </tab>         
     </tabs>
   </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I'm not sure how you would do it from the designer but, you can access the Ribbon.xml file and add it that way.

Note that that is only for a custom tab.  If you want to add it to a built in tab you need to specify it using the idMso of that tab.  For example, if you wanted to add it to the appointment tab you could use:

```
<tab idMso="TabAppointment">
</tab>
```

Here is where you can find the [control ids](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582).